# How to push key as iterative value in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i have a two for loop contains checking the each loop length and push into key value pair of array

```
 const reader = new FileReader(); // filereader
  reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]); // read as text
  reader.onload = () => {
      const allText = reader.result;
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split('\t');
    var lines = [];

    for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split('\t');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {

            var tarr = [];
            for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {

              
                tarr.push(headers[j]+":"+data[j]);
            }
            
             lines.push(tarr);

        }
        
    }
```

and my output is getting below

```
[Array(2),Array(2)]

output now i'm getting

     [
      [
       0:'product:PA123'
       1:'value:123'
       2:'price:$234'
       ],
       [
       0:'product:PA234'
       1:'value:235'
       2:'price:$24'
       ],
    
      ]
    
    
    expected output
     [
       [
        product:PA123,
        value :123,
        price :234
       ],
       [
        product:PA123,
        value :123,
        price :234
        ]
    
      ]
```

i need to push headers[j] as key but i can't.How to do that in JS ? I'm literally new . please bare me.THanks

apologize for bad formatting.

Comment: Please share the full code with the output you are expecting.

Comment: The marked statement looks okay, but what are you doing in the statement below? `lines.push(tarr)` assuming lines is another array, this would push an array into an array?

Comment: Hi , can you provide the definition of `header` variable?

Comment: @omidh my output is 
`0:Array(2)
0: {product:PA123}
1: {value :123}
2: {price :234}`

but its need to be 
`0:Array(2)
0: [{product:PA123,value :123,price :234}]`

Comment: you are already getting your expected result. dont confuse with keys '0:' or '1:'. developer console shows array index as its key to make it more readable. your output is not clear though, do you want your output as "array of string array" or "array of model"?

Comment: @Jake Array of string array

Comment: then you already getting your expected result. to confirm console it as console.log(JSON.stringify(lines))

Comment: @Jake
getting result is
`[0:[Array(2) 0: [{product:PA123,value :123,price :234}]]

expected
 [
  0:{product:PA123,value :123,price :234}...]`

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
You already getting your expected result. just dont get confuse with index keys 0, 1, 2. Dev console shows index of array as key to make it more readable. still you are confuse just console stringified result.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(lines));
```

For output as array of model: i.e.

```
[
   {
      product:PA123,
      value :123,
      price :234
   },
   {
      product:PA123,
      value :123,
      price :234
    }    
 ]
// code
for (var i=0; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i];
    if (data.length == headers.length) {

        var model= {};
        for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) 
        {
          model[headers[j]] = data[j];
        }    
        lines.push(model);    
    }    
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(lines));
```

For output as array of string array: i.e.

```
[
   [
      "product:PA123",
      "value :123",
      "price :234"
   ],
   [
      "product:PA123",
      "value :123",
      "price :234"
    }    
 ]

 //code
 for (var i=0; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i];
    if (data.length == headers.length) {

        var stringArray= [];
        for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) 
        {
          stringArray.push(headers[j]+":"+data[j]);
        }    
        lines.push(stringArray);    
    }    
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(lines));
```

Hope this will answer your query.

Comment: you rock.. it worked...

Comment: that's grate. dont forget to mark it as answerd. here is stackbliz link if needed https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8cv9ef?file=index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i];
        if (data.length == headers.length) {

            var tarr = [];
            for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) 
            {
               let a = headers[j];
               let b = {}  
               b[headers[j]] = data[j];
               tarr.push(b)****
            }
            
             lines.push(tarr);

        }
        
    }
```

Comment: it print array inside array of object can it be single array with key and value

Comment: 0:Array(2) 0: {product:PA123} 1: {value :123} 2: {price :234} but its need to be 0:Array(2) 0: [{product:PA123,value :123,price :234}]

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following line to this.

:from

```
tarr.push(headers[j]+":"+data[j])
```

: to

```
tarr.push({[headers[j]]:data[j]})
```